# Marking a Sharp Angle with Arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows, tkz-euclide

How would you mark an angle as follows,

[image]

MWE:

```
documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        \coordinate [label={[label distance=-3pt]45:{$O$}}] (O) at (0,0);
        \coordinate [label=above:N] (N) at (0,1.5);
        \coordinate (N') at (0,-1.5);
        \coordinate (E') at (-1.5,0);
        \coordinate (E) at (1.5,0);
        \draw[dashed] (E) -- (E');
        \draw[dashed] (O) -- (N);
        \coordinate [label={[label distance=0pt]-90:{$B$}}] (B) at (-120:5);
        \coordinate [label={[label distance=-3pt]-45:{$A$}}] (A) at ($(B)+(2.5,0)$);
        \draw (B) -- (A) -- (O);
        \draw (O) -- (B);
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=2.5](B,O,A){$30^\circ$};
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.7](B,O,A);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Just draw the arrow like normal, but insert control points in between (see TikZ manual), if you use TikZ. Unfortunately it's hard to help you without a MWE showing what you've got so far.

Comment: Please see edits above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can play with the outgoing and incoming angles of the line.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
  \coordinate [label={[label distance=-3pt]45:{$O$}}] (O) at (0,0);
  \coordinate [label=above:N] (N) at (0,1.5);
  \coordinate (N') at (0,-1.5);
  \coordinate (E') at (-1.5,0);
  \coordinate (E) at (1.5,0);
  \draw[dashed] (E) -- (E');
  \draw[dashed] (O) -- (N);
  \coordinate [label={[label distance=0pt]-90:{$B$}}] (B) at (-120:5);
  \coordinate [label={[label distance=-3pt]-45:{$A$}}] (A) at ($(B)+(2.5,0)$);
  \draw (B) -- (A) -- (O);
  \draw (O) -- (B);
  % \tkzLabelAngle[pos=2.5](B,O,A){$30^\circ$};
  \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.7](B,O,A);
  \draw[stealth-] (-105:0.7) to[out=-90,in=-150,looseness=1.7] +(1,-0.3) node[anchor=west,inner sep=2pt]{$30^\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

As an alternative control points can be used to bend the line, e.g.

```
\draw[stealth-] (-105:0.7)  .. controls ++(0.05,-0.5) and ++(-0.6,-0.2) .. +(1,-0.3) node[anchor=west,inner sep=2pt]{$30^\circ$};
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer thanks!